# how to delete a row in gridview if using template field

Tags: asp.net

I have tried so many times but i am not able to delete a row in GRID VIEW. I didn't create any database.I am just storing all the values of the text field in the GRID VIEW.If i want to delete a row in the GRID VIEW using template field button means,what will be the solution.

This is the way i am storing and populating values in GridView.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
dr[0] = lbltxtcustomer.Text;
dr[1] = FNtxt.Text;
dr[2] = LNtxt.Text;
dr[3] = DrpdownMonth.Text + "/" + DrpdownDay.Text + "/" + DrpdownYear.Text;
dr[4] = lbltxtage.Text;
dr[5] = txtEmail.Text;
dr[6] = TxtPhone.Text;
dr[7] = Txtlocation.Text;
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
BindGrid()
```

;

Comment: you must have made dynamic datatable for storing a value in gridview, is it soo?needed some code for explanation...

Comment: http://dotprogramming.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-delete-multiple-rows-from.html

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/267426/how-to-delete-the-gridview-row-with-templatefield

Comment: this is the way i am storing and populating values in GridView.                                                      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
dr[0] = lbltxtcustomer.Text;
dr[1] = FNtxt.Text;
dr[2] = LNtxt.Text;
dr[3] = DrpdownMonth.Text + "/" + DrpdownDay.Text + "/" + DrpdownYear.Text;
dr[4] = lbltxtage.Text;
dr[5] = txtEmail.Text;
dr[6] = TxtPhone.Text;
dr[7] = Txtlocation.Text;
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
BindGrid();

Answer (score 0):

Try This

> HTML Markup

Below is the HTML Markup of the APS.Net GridView. Here I am making use the CommandFieldand OnRowDeleting event to delete the GridView Row. Hence I will apply the JavaScript Confirmation Box to the CommandFieldDelete Button itself.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass = "Grid" runat="server" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Item" HeaderText="Item" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

> Applying the JavaScript Confirmation Box to the GridView CommandField
>   Delete Button

To apply the JavaScript Confirmation Box, I am looking for the Button in the Controls of the GridView Cell Index 2 since it has the CommandField. Once

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string item = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
        foreach (Button button in e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            if (button.CommandName == "Delete")
            {
                button.Attributes["onclick"] = "if(!confirm('Do you want to delete " + item + "?')){ return false; };";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Delete the ASP.Net GridView Row using CommandField and OnRowDeleting
>   event

Below is the code to delete the ASP.Net GridView Row using OnRowDeleting event

```
protected void OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
    DataTable dt = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable;
    dt.Rows[index].Delete();
    ViewState["dt"] = dt;
    BindGrid();
}
```